# Does every Young diagram have a unique minimal major index?

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups, young-tableaux, descent

Given a Young diagram, $Y_\rho$, corresponding to an irreducible complex representation $\rho$ of the symmetric group $S_n$, we can associate a set of major indices $\{ d^\rho_1,\ldots,d^\rho_{k_\rho}\}$, each of which is defined by choosing a standard tableaux on $Y_\rho$ and summing the descents. The $d_i^\rho$ are sometimes referred to as the degrees of $\rho$ and $k_\rho$ is the hook length of $Y_\rho$ (or the dimension of $\rho$).

The question is in two parts. First, for a fixed $\rho$ is the minimal degree unique? Perhaps there is some algorithm that produces a tableaux with minimal major index?

Secondly, can two non-isomorphic irreducibles, $\rho$ and $\mu$ say, have the same minimal degrees?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Is your second question asking whether two distinct Young diagrams can have the same minimal-major-index-of-a-standard-Young-tableau? If so, they clearly can for high enough $n$, since the number of Young diagrams of size $n$ (that is, the number of partitions of $n$) grows faster than the number of possible minimal-major-indices.

Comment: Your first question is interesting and appears to have a positive answer.

Comment: OK, the first question has a positive answer. It follows from Proposition 7.19.11 in Richard Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics, volume 2* (for $\mu = \emptyset$), once you observe that the lowest nonzero coefficient of the polynomial $s_{\lambda}\left(1,q,q^2,\ldots\right)$ is $1$ (because there is a unique semistandard Young tableau of shape $\lambda$ with content $\lambda$, and all the other semistandard Young tableaux of shape $\lambda$ have bigger content in an appropriate sense of "bigger").

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you Darij.

Comment: Much research has since been done related to this question. See [Sara C. Billey, Matjaž Konvalinka, Joshua P. Swanson, *Tableaux posets and the fake degrees of coinvariant algebras*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.07386) for a recent work.